# Using AS3 to download a file from a server that isn't web accessible

Tags: php, actionscript-3, file

I have managed to create an AS3 script that uses file.download(urlRequest); - this is working fine when referencing a location that is web accessible. Is it possible to get flash to reference a location on the server it resides? I want to make the files it has access to downloading as secure as possible.

I realise that I can reference a PHP file in the AS3 to initiate the download but this isn't working when using a browser window within a Silverlight application so need the flash to do the downloading if possible.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is a Flash FTP API's, you should Google for them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use an htaccess rule on the server? If the request originates from a different host / server then respond with a 403 error. If the request is from the same host / server then download the file?

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^www.your-site.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This is not the most secure method of preventing access, as referrer headers can be spoofed or disabled in browsers.

Another idea:

The url for the file is pushed through a php script. If the ip address of the request is not in the database, then do not allow the file to be downloaded. Use your flash to post a request to the server with an ip address (the server adds the ip to a whitelist in a database), then perform your `file.download(urlRequest)`?

Again not the most secure as someone could post their ip, spoof their referrer header and THEN get the files...

Still, better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think any security even if it can be found out is a bit more secure for me. I take it at the end of the day flash/as3 can't access the server like a php script can to reference a non-web facing directory on the server.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Flash is client-side and cannot directly communicate with the server.

Comment: As I thought... I'll try implement one of your methods as it will help secure it a bit at least.